# async map doesnt reflect changes in the method body

Tags: flutter, dart

The list returned from this code is empty. assume that formatUser is an async method that formats the user from the remote to a suitable format. why is that filterUsers  list does'nt change when we map the other list?

```
Future<List<User>> fetchUsers() async{
final list<User> usersFromRemote = await getUserFromRemote();

final List<User> filterUsers = [];

usersFromRemote.map((user) async {
   if(user.name != 'jim')
{
     filterUsers.add(await formatUser(user));
}
});

return filterUsers;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `map` wrongly. You need to use filter(aka `where`) and `map` for your use case.

```
Future<List<User>> fetchUsers() async {
  final List<User> usersFromRemote = await getUserFromRemote();

  final List<User> filterUsers = await Future.wait(
    usersFromRemote.where((u) => u.name != 'jim').map(
      (user) async {
        return formatUser(user);
      },
    ),
  );
  return filterUsers;
}
```

Or you can use `forEach` but which is not very functional.

Answer (score 0):

Use [forEach()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html) instead of `map()`. According to the [docs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/Iterable/map.html), unless the iterable returned by `map()` is iterated over, the transforming function will not be called.